# Custom query, multiple custom keys

Tags: post-meta, customization, query-string

I need to get posts that have two meta-values.

It tried the following code, but this is getting empty result

```
<?php
 $featuredquery = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'article_level' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Hovedsak')
    AND (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'article_genre' AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'X6.no (Spill og underholdning)')
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 4
 "; 

 $featuredposts = $wpdb->get_results($featuredquery, OBJECT);
?>
```

Any ideas for this? 
I tried searching around, but didn't find anything that suited me.. :/

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an SQL expert, but I would think you might have to JOIN twice to pick two distinct rows out of `wp_postmeta`:

```
 $featuredquery = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
    JOIN $wpdb->postmeta article_level ON
      ( wposts.ID = article_level.post_id AND
        article_level.meta_key = 'article_level' )
    JOIN $wpdb->postmeta article_genre ON 
      ( wposts.ID = article_genre.post_id AND
        article_genre.meta_key = 'article_genre' )
    WHERE article_level.meta_value = 'Hovedsak'
    AND article_genre.meta_value = 'X6.no (Spill og underholdning)'
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 4
 ";
```

Comment: would be correct.  I've done queries like that before and they work without a hitch.

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond *Which* would be correct? The way he originally wrote the query, or this way I rewrote it?

Comment: Hmm, I would guess that this was a solution, but it didn't work for me. It just gave me an empty result..

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the new `tax_query` option to `query_posts()`, WordPress 3.1 will add a `meta_query` argument:

```
query_posts( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'article_level',
            'value' => 'Hovedsak',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'article_genre',
            'value' => 'X6.no (Spill og underholdning)',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Not quite here yet, but worth mentioning.